# Ошибка при загрузки документа на сервера Вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу программу, которая конвертирует фотки из вк в один pdf. Я добился этой цели, но теперь нужно, чтобы этот pdf отправлялся пользователю. Для этого вк просит, чтобы документ был загружен на сервера(подробнее тут [https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=10.%20Загрузка%20документов](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=10.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)). Следуя шагам из документации, я пытаюсь отправить POST-запрос и получить ответ

```
filename = 'C:\\Users\\79859\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Photo_vk\\' + name + '.pdf'
upload_url = vk.docs.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id=id_moy, type='doc')['upload_url']
request = requests.post(upload_url, files={'doc': open(filename, "rb")})
```

Данный код выдает такую ошибку: '{"error":"no_file","error_descr":"no_file"}'

Я проверил права доступа(все разрешено) и пробовал загрузить на сервер обычную jpg фотку, используя схожий метод  photos.getWallUploadServer. И ошибки не было! То есть фотография была успешно загружена

Никак не могу понять с чем связана эта ошибка при загрузке на сервера. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: `filename = 'C:\\Users\\79859\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Photo_vk\\' + name + '.pdf'` - очень плохое решение. Используйте класс `Path` библиолтеки `pathlib`, либо `os.path.join`

Comment: `files={'doc': open(filename, "rb")}` - предположу, что сюда надо передавать не дескриптор файла, а содержимого самого файла. то есть надо сделать `read` от открытого файла и передать в словарь

Comment: Я просто начинаю тоько программировать, поэтому очень интересно почему указание пути к файлу - плохой вариант ?
Я пробовал передать fie.read(), но , к сожалению, проблема не решилась

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась, но не тем способом, который я указал выше.
Использовал в итоге метод document_message (вот ссылка https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html)

Answer (score 1):

Мой пример:

```
elif file.endswith('.gif'):
    id_doc = vk_api.upload.VkUpload(self.vk).document_wall(path, group_id=self.group_id)['doc']['id']                                                 
if title and id_doc:
    self.vk.wall.post(owner_id=f'-{self.group_id}', message=title,
                      attachments=f'doc-{self.group_id}_{id_doc}')
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя бага, нужно использовать **file**

```
print(requests.post(url, files={'file': open("123.gif", "rb")}).json())
```